# ICE (Emergency) contacts from lock screen - how to access when SIP is configured?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens, voip, emergency-calls

Using Android version 4.4.2 (on Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini).
I have added one of my contacts to the OS built-in ICE contact group and assigned to one of the four emergency contact buttons that are shown when selecting "Emergency Call" from the lock screen.
However, since configuring the stock SIP (VoIP) client, the phone prompts the user to select Mobile Call or Internet Call before making the call. Unfortunately, although the dialler application seems to be awaiting user response, the prompt is not visible until the screen is unlocked, rendering the emergency contact unusable by a stranger in an emergency.
Is there a way to override this (preferably without using 3rd party applications)?